Dial.to Not working for localhost
I'm currently participating in the Solana boot camp available on YouTube: Boot Camp Video at the timestamp 2:03:27 / 11:08:04.
I'm not seeing any results in Dial.to and suspect it might be related to a CORS error. Here’s the relevant portion of my api/vote/route.ts file:
import { ActionGetResponse, ACTIONS_CORS_HEADERS } from '@solana/actions';

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const actionMetadata: ActionGetResponse = {
    icon: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/JavaScript-logo.png",
    title: "Vote For Your Favorite type of Peanut Butter",
    description: "Vote between chrunchy and smooth peanut butter",
    label: "vote",
  };
  return Response.json(actionMetadata, { headers: ACTIONS_CORS_HEADERS });
}

Please refer to the attached screenshot for the error message:

You can try turning off SHIELD if using Brave Browser 
Or use Firefox - that should resolve the issue.
If using Chrome - You can also try setting this flag;
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
